# Getting the value of previos field with yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

Sometimes it would be handy to get the previously entered field values, and process them.

**Example:** the second field (function name) of this snippet is always the camelCase version of the first field (description) in my workflow.

```
describe('$1', function $2() {
  $0
});
```

To write lisp function to do this, one should know how to get the value of the first field.

Comment: You don't need to do it that way, check the [Mirrors with transformations](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-6) section in yasnippet's manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Yasnippet Documentation](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-6) in the *Mirrors with Transformations*, you can have a `$1` substitution multiple times in your snippet, but each one can be transformed. Try this:

```
describe('$1', function ${1:$(camelize yas-text)}() {
  $0
});
```

That said, you'll need a `camelize` function written in Lisp. Check out the examples on the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CamelCase), like:

```
(defun camelize (s)
  "Convert under_score string S to CamelCase string."
  (mapconcat 'identity (mapcar
                        '(lambda (word) (capitalize (downcase word)))
                        (split-string s "_")) ""))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: [Don't quote the `(lambda ...)` form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948325/why-not-quoting-lambda)

Comment: Thanks, it worked nice. I modified it a bit to my specific case.
(defun my/camelize (s)
  "Convert under_score string S to CamelCase string."
  (store-substring (mapconcat 'identity (mapcar
                        (lambda (word) (capitalize (downcase word)))
                        (split-string s "[-_ ]+")) "") 0 (if (> (length s) 0)
                                                             (downcase (substring s 0 1)))))